# scalaでsprayのimportができません。

Tags: scala

サンプルコードにsprayというライブラリが使わていたので、インタプリタで試してみようと思った所、以下のエラーがでました。

scala自体は最近はじめたばかりでこういったケースにどう対処すればよいのかがわかりません。
rubyでいうところのgemみたいなものをインストールする必要があるのかなと思ったのですが、
その方法を調べていたもののわからず・・・。

```
scala> import spray.json.JsValue
:7: error: not found: value spray
       import spray.json.JsValue
```

どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？

それともインタプリタで、importはそもそもできないとかでしょうか。

宜しくお願いします。

追記

```
➜  ~  scala -cp spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import spray.json.JsValue
:7: error: not found: value spray
       import spray.json.JsValue
              ^
scala> spray.json.JsValue
:8: error: not found: value spray
              spray.json.JsValue
              ^

scala> spray
:8: error: not found: value spray
              spray
              ^
```

Comment: Scala 2.10を使っているなら2.10用のJarをダウンロードしないとダメです。こちらからどうぞ http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.spray/spray-json_2.10/1.3.2

Comment: このへんがJava/Scalaの面倒くさいところで、SBTとかMavenとかで自動的に依存関係を解決するツールを使わないと手に負えません。なのでインタープリタを使っている人はほとんどいないんじゃないかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

これでいかがでしょうか。

```
scala -cp spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar
```

JARはmavenというリポジトリにあります。
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.spray/spray-json_2.11

こんな感じで、importできていることがわかります。

```
$ scala -cp spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_31).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> spray.json.JsFalse
res0: spray.json.JsFalse.type = false

scala>
```

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。質問本文の下部に追記という形で追加させていただいたのですが、scala -cp spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jarをやってもダメでした。コマンドログはありますが、なにか作業を間違ってますでしょうか？